# Why is path parameter shown as query parameter in FastAPI docs?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I am developing APIs using FastAPI.

I have set the router as the following:

```
router = APIRouter(
    prefix="/customer-profiles",
    tags=["customer-profiles"],
    responses={
        404: {
            "description": "Not found"
        }
    },
)

@router.get(
    "/{customer_id}",
    response_model=schemas.CustomerProfileDetail
)
async def get_profile(
    profile: schemas.CustomerProfileDetail = Depends(models.CustomerProfile.get_profile_or_404)
) -> schemas.CustomerProfileDetail:
    return profile
```

The issue here is, in the FastAPI docs, the path parameter is shown as **query** parameter.

[image]

Due to this, I believe that I am not able to parse multiple Path parameters as I am only presented **id** field in the following API.

[image]

What could be the issue behind this? And how can this be resolved?

Comment: Thanks. It seenms that we need not pass path parametes if we are using Depends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally resolved this issue.

So, the issue was in Dependency Injection. The dependency function was taking **id** as parameter due to which **customer_id** became query parameter
So, when I resolved:

```
def get_profile_or_404(id: str)
```

to:

```
def get_profile_404(customer_id: str)
```

for the route:

```
@router.get(
    "/{customer_id}",
    response_model=schemas.CustomerProfileDetail
)
async def get_profile(
    profile: schemas.CustomerProfileDetail = Depends(models.CustomerProfile.get_profile_or_404)
) -> schemas.CustomerProfileDetail:
    return profile
```

My issue was resolved.

It seems that we need to have the same parameter name in the dependency function as well.